# Get the index of a child node in parent's node using xpath

Tags: html, dom, xpath

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="a">Name</th>
        <th class="b">Old </th>
        <th class="x">New</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the above snippet using X-path,I need to get the index of the "**th**"w.r.to "**tr**" node which is 3.How can I achieve this?

I tried to find the node using

```
//aside//table//tr/th[text() = 'New']
```

But I do not know to find it's relative index

Is there any axis-specifier to get the index of it?

Answer (score 2):

Try below XPath to get node index:

```
//table//tr/th[text() = 'New']/count(preceding-sibling::th) + 1
```

Comment: I believe it is "count(//aside//table//tr/th[text() = 'New Value']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1" ?? Correct me if its wrong

Comment: Yep. This syntax is also should be acceptable. My expression should work for XPath 2.0, 3.0